Multiple LDAP configuration on sonarqube server
I am trying to configure multiple LDAP servers on my SonarQube server. Each LDAP server works properly when configured individually for testing.
I tried to configure multiple servers using the method available on the official SonarQube website:
# Configuration for multiple LDAP servers
ldap.servers=server1,server2
ldap.server1.url=ldap://server1:1389
ldap.server1.user.baseDn=dc=dept1,dc=com
ldap.server2.url=ldap://server2:1389
ldap.server2.user.baseDn=dc=dept2,dc=com


However, this approach is not working for me.
Can anyone provide a proper working way and a solution to resolve this issue?

Can you clarify how this ties into Realm (per the tag) which is part of MongoDB Realm the database?
